# Contourplot, how to make a circular area?

Tags: homework

I am trying to illustrate [this math problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2839398/change-of-variable-with-circle-and-ln/2839409#2839409) with a graph.

I tried several things, amongst other:

```
ContourPlot[{4 <= x^2 + y^2 <= 25}, {x, 0, Infinity}, {y, 0, 
  Infinity}]
```

How should I write it?

Thank you very much.

Comment: `ContourPlot` is used to plot level curves. Is that what you want? Your code indicates that you want to plot a continuous range of level curves.

Comment: RegionPlot is for plotting inequalities.

Comment: @C.E. I don't get the thing with level curves. I have two variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want ?

```
RegionPlot[{4 <= x^2 + y^2 <= 25}, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}]
```

[image]

Comment: Yes @Lotus, this is what I want. I added  Axes -> True. How can I make it more beautiful?

Comment: RegionPlot has many many options to make it look beautiful. Check it out !

Comment: Hahaha look, it got out of control really fast! RegionPlot[{4 <= x^2 + y^2 <= 25}, {x, -7, 7}, {y, -7, 7}, 
 Axes -> True, ColorFunction -> "DarkRainbow", 
 PlotLegends -> "Expressions", Mesh -> 30, 
 MeshShading -> {{Red, Yellow}, {Pink, Orange}}]

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use ContourPlot this might be another option:

```
ContourPlot[Boole[4 <= x^2 + y^2 <= 25], {x, -8, 8}, {y, -8, 8}]
```

which gives

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Annulus`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Annulus):

```
Region @ Annulus[{2, 5}]
```

[image]

Here, I just use [`Region`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Region) to visualize the annulus. If you want the portion of the annulus in the first quadrant:

```
Region @ Annulus[{0, 0}, {2, 5}, {0, Pi/2}]
```

[image]

The nice thing about this approach is that the annulus is computable. For example, using this representation one can solve the integral in the linked question:

```
Integrate[x^3 y^2 Log[x^2+y^2], {x,y} ∈ Annulus[{0,0},{2,5},{0,Pi/2}]]
```

> -(4/735) (77997 + 896 Log[2] - 546875 Log[5])

Answer (score 0):

While `RegionPlot` is the easiest approach, you could also use `ContourPlot`

```
ContourPlot[x^2 + y^2, {x, -6, 6}, {y, -6, 6},
 Contours -> {4, 25},
 ContourShading -> {None, LightBlue, None},
 Axes -> True]
```

[image]